# Como alterar a opacidade de um elemento excluindo sua borda?

Tags: css

Estou estilizando um link que possui uma borda e gostaria de que quando o cursor do mouse estive em cima do mesmo, apenas o texto ficasse mais claro, mantendo a borda na mesma cor original.

Usando `opacity`, não estou conseguindo excluir a borda também ficar mais clara:

```
a#link:hover {
    color: #000;    
    opacity: .6;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

Existe alguma forma aplicar opacidade apenas no texto e excluir as bordas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A opacidade funciona no elemento como um todo, e isto afeta tanto o `border`, `color` e `background`.

Para aplicar uma opacidade no texto você pode utilizar a opção `rgba` apenas no `color`, sendo que o último dos 4 valores do `rgba` se refere justamente à opacidade da cor (*alpha*).

Segue um exemplo de como fica:

```css
a#link{
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1); /* 0,0,0 = cor preta, 1 significa totalmente opaco */
   border: solid 1px #000;
}

a#link:hover {
   color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); /* 0,0,0 = cor preta, 0.6 significa 60% opaco */
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="#">Link</a>
```